# Spring Webflux Security Resource Server Multi Tenant - Issuer by REST path

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on implementing Multi-Tenant Resoure Server with Webflux Security.

This is my current config:

```
    @Bean
    fun securityConfig(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain? {
        http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/path1", "/path2").authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer { rs ->
                rs.authenticationManagerResolver(
                    JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(
                        "http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/realm1",
                        "http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/realm2"
                    )
                )
            }
        return http.build()
    }
```

This works and I have **/path1** and **/path2** secured by either **trusted_issuer1** or **trusted_issuer2**. This allows me to call path1 using either oauth2 issuers but this is not what I want.

I need to have **/path1** secured by **ONLY** **trust_issuer1** and **/path2** secured by **ONLY** **trust_issuer2** and I'm not sure how I can achieve that, any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: by setting up 2 seperete security configs?

Comment: tried that by setting @Order(1) and @Order(2) but only the first one is applied

Comment: So you are claiming that spring security is broken? Or that the documentation for setting this up is faulty? Because i expect you have read the full documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-webflux-multiple-filter-chains